# Firebase Permission Denied with Pyrebase library

Tags: firebase

I have setup a Firebase account and a database.

I have copied the config with the API key into my Python code.

I still get a 401 Permission denied error on Python 3.5

```
import pyrebase
config = {
"apiKey": "*****",
"authDomain": "***-bot.firebaseapp.com",
"databaseURL": "https://***-bot.firebaseio.com",
"storageBucket": "ebo-bot.appspot.com"
}

firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)
db = firebase.database()
data = {"name": "Mortimer 'Morty' Smith"}
db.child("users").child("Morty").set(data)
```

My database rules are set to:

```
{
 "rules": {
".read": "auth != null",
".write": "auth != null"
}
}
```

Answer (score 13):

I ran into this same issue trying to upload data to the database.
I reread the beginning of: https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase/blob/master/README.md

```
import pyrebase

config = {
  "apiKey": "apiKey",
  "authDomain": "projectId.firebaseapp.com",
  "databaseURL": "https://databaseName.firebaseio.com",
  "storageBucket": "projectId.appspot.com",
  "serviceAccount": "path/to/serviceAccountCredentials.json"
}

firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)
```

Add the serviceAccount entry into the configuration with a path to a key that you can download from Firebase.

[image]

To get there: Settings > Project Settings > Service Accounts > Generate New Private Key.

Put that key in some desired location and put that location in the "serviceAccount" path.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Didn't think the serviceAccount was necessary when we've successfully signed in but... This worked!

Comment: @Vitor I would advice not to add a serviceAccount, this skips all security rules you have set. Rather, pass the user['idToken'] as Jose indicated in their answer. See also https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase/blob/master/README.md#authentication for more detail

Answer (score 2):

set method is missing the user['idToken'], and you forgot to authenticate, try:

```
import pyrebase
config = {
"apiKey": "*****",
"authDomain": "***-bot.firebaseapp.com",
"databaseURL": "https://***-bot.firebaseio.com",
"storageBucket": "ebo-bot.appspot.com"
}

firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)
db = firebase.database()
auth = firebase.auth()

user = auth.sign_in_with_email_and_password("usernamehere@user.com", "passwordhere")

data = {"name": "Mortimer 'Morty' Smith"}
db.child("users").child("Morty").set(data,user['idToken'])
```

(you also need to create an user before running this, go to your firebase dashboard and click on the authentication tab, you can add users there)

Comment: @skunkwerk note that this also applies to the other methods, such as get, etc. See https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase/blob/master/README.md#authentication