# send an image to google fire-base using python

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-storage, pyrebase

i want to store image in google firebase

```
import pyrebase
config = { "apiKey": "apiKey", "authDomain": "projectId.firebaseapp.com", 
"databaseURL": "https://databaseName.firebaseio.com", "storageBucket": 
"projectId.appspot.com" } 
firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(config) 
 storage.child("images/example.jpg").put("example2.jpg", user['idToken'])
```

---

i want an api to store an image in firebase,or if there is any other method to post the image to firebase. i tried this but its showing wrong password and when i try to create token this is the error :'NoneType' object has no attribute 'service_account_email'

Comment: i don't know much about python configuration with firebase but after i saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41253388/10182897) answer i think you forgot `serviceAccount`

Comment: from where *user* is coming ? It is nowhere defined

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `firebase` package: https://pypi.org/project/firebase/

**Setup**

```
from firebase import Firebase

config = {
  "apiKey": "apiKey",
  "authDomain": "projectId.firebaseapp.com",
  "databaseURL": "https://databaseName.firebaseio.com",
  "storageBucket": "projectId.appspot.com",
  "serviceAccount": "path/to/serviceAccountCredentials.json"
}

firebase = Firebase(config)
```

---

**Storage**

The storage service allows you to upload images to Firebase.

```
storage = firebase.storage()
```

**child**

Just like with the Database service, you can build paths to your data with the Storage service.

```
storage.child("images/example.jpg")
```

**put**

The put method takes the path to the local file and an optional user token.

```
storage = firebase.storage()

# as admin
storage.child("images/example.jpg").put("example2.jpg")

# as user
storage.child("images/example.jpg").put("example2.jpg", user['idToken'])
```

**download**

The download method takes the path to the saved database file and the name you want the downloaded file to have.

```
storage.child("images/example.jpg").download("downloaded.jpg")
```

**get_url**

The get_url method takes the path to the saved database file and returns the storage url.

```
storage.child("images/example.jpg").get_url()

>> https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/storage- 
url.appspot.com/o/images%2Fexample.jpg?alt=media
```